# why is jquery ajax not sending the data in get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm setting up a page where our staff can view a list of items that should be on the shelf and then confirm if the items are there, or send in an alert if there's a problem.

I'm trying to create one function for each situation (item present, item not present, information incorrect) where each function will pass the correct parameters for that situation to a generic function which will make the actual ajax request.

This function is triggered by a button click (when the item is present and correct) and it logs the data correctly:

```
function log (rec_id,offset) {
    console.log("On Shelf \r\nRecord_Id: "+rec_id+"\r\nOffset: "+offset);
    var rdata =[];
    rdata['id'] = rec_id;
    rdata['status'] = 1;
    rdata['branch'] = $("#branch").val();
    rdata['loc_code'] = $("#location_code").val();
    console.log("log function");
    console.log(rdata);

    log_item(rec_id,offset,rdata);      
}
```

this is what is output to the log:

```
[id: 1833049, status: 1, branch: "1", loc_code: "mnlp"]
```

the log_item function makes the ajax request

```
function log_item(rec_id, offset, rdata) {
    console.log("Logging Item: i"+rec_id+"a");
    console.log("log_item function");
    console.log(rdata);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'logItem.php',
        data: rdata
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $("#form").foundation('close');
    });
}
```

It too logs the data correctly

```
[id: 1833049, status: 1, branch: "1", loc_code: "mnlp"]
```

But when I view the requests sent, these parameters are not getting passed in request.

Comment: Specify method: "POST" in the Ajax request

Comment: Is there a reason GET won't work? I wrote logItem.php to retrieve the parameters from $_GET ?

Comment: you can't send json data via Get method

Comment: Shouldn't it be an object instead of an array? I don't think [] is going to be passed as an object.

Comment: I understand it looks like JSON when I log it to the console, but it should just be a JS array which the $.ajax() function is supposed to handle

Comment: @misher jQuery converts its to a query string and appends it to the URL. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/

Comment: what makes you think that your data has not been sent via GET? please show your firebugs output of your request.

Comment: Looking at it with Chrome Developer tools. I'll export the logs from that after I look up how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is here.

```
var rdata =[];
```

Change it to

```
var rdata ={};
```

Comment: That did the trick. From what I understand, that changes it to an object instead of an array, any idea why the array didn't work?

Comment: javascript does not support associative array. array can have only index like 0,1,2 .(always numeric).
For storing key value js has object.

Comment: @cdm014 The jQuery `ajax` function uses jQuery `param` to convert the data into the query string for a GET request: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/. As you can see from the documentation, it supports array as an input type, but you passed in an empty array (`length == 0`), so it produced nothing.